# Set / Unset Underline TextView

Tags: android, underline

I have managed to make underline in my textview. Here is the code :

```
txtOrder1.setPaintFlags(txtOrder1.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Now i want to remove that underline. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try like below code:

```
txtOrder1.setPaintFlags(txtOrder1.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Answer (score 1):

For remove the Underline use like this

```
txtOrder1.setPaintFlags(txtOrder1.getPaintFlags() | ~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

or

```
txtOrder1.setPaintFlags(0);
```

Comment: The operations are bitwise, so this does not work, you must use & instead. also put `~ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG` in brackets

Comment: I just added another solution also, first one may work or may not, second solution is a working, a issue may have multiple workaround..